# 400 BadRequest: Missing Credential feathersjs authentication-local

Tags: node.js, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate a user using @feathersjs/authentication-local, Though I'm giving proper username & password, I get following response

```
{
    "name": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Missing credentials",
    "code": 400,
    "className": "bad-request",
    "data": {
        "message": "Missing credentials"
    },
    "errors": {}
}
```

DB property of `user` entity is `username` & `password`. My configuration is as following

```
const settings = {
    secret: 'super&secret',
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    entityUsernameField: 'username',
    entityPasswordField: 'password'
};

app.configure(authentication(settings))
        .configure(local());

app.service('authentication').hooks({
        before: {
            create: [authentication.hooks.authenticate(['local', 'jwt'])],
            remove: [],
        }
    });
```

I've added `"strategy": "local"` on request body. What am I missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there is no Express [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware registered. As shown in the [feathers-chat](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat) it has to be [set up before authentication](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/master/src/app.js#L29).

Comment: Actually @Daff, I had the bodyParser middleware and registered before the authentication hooks. Lately I used feathers generator to create the authentication service which was successful. I assume there was some conflict at `default.json`. In my service & schema model name is `users` but i had to use `"entity": "user"` in `default.json`

Answer (score 0):

Missing Credential feathersjs authentication-local, this error may occur due to following reasons:

1. You are missing fields when sending the request. Usually, if there is any data present it throws an error as NotAuthenticated: Invalid login if the credentials are not correct.
2. Escape fields in default.json to avoid referring to system environmental variables. [Refer to this](https://github.com/feathersjs/authentication/issues/508).